# Using Ninject WCF Extension with WCF Web Service

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a WCF web service in which I want to use my Repositories and Services which I wish to dependency inject into my WCF web service, however the Ninject WCF Extension example pretty much has a ctor which is instantiating an instance of each dependency, which I don't want, I wanted a purer dependency injection.

Has anyone had any success with using Ninject with WCF, Google seems to return little relevant results for the topics I am looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code behind for [TimeService](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/blob/Maintenance_2.2/src/Examples/WcfTimeService/TimeService.svc) has:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfTimeService.TimeService" CodeBehind="TimeService.svc.cs" **Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory"** %>
```

The [bastard injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348727/dependency-injection-with-multiple-repositories/2348971#2348971) ctors confuse the matter - Ninject will choose the most specific constructor. The general problem with the sample is that it's covering all the bases (IIS Hosted, EXE hosted, Service Hosted), and WCF doesnt exactly make all this stuff easy to manage either (@Ian Davis: I could easily be wrong, can you provide some more detail please , perhaps in the form of a summary of what the samples illustrate in the README, and perhaps more detail in the why of the various cases where you've used BI?)

Answer (score 2):

The way I am currently using Ninject (v3) with my WCF is based on the Ninject WCF extension and [Pieter De Rycke's great blog post](http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/using-an-ioc-container-to-create-wcf-service-instances/).

In a nutshell, here's what I'm doing:

1) Via NuGet, I've added a reference to Ninject.Extensions.Wcf into my WCF project. This creates the App_Start folder with NinjectWebCommon.cs, which takes care of initializing Ninject.

2) Typically, you'd set up your Ninject mappings in the CreateKernel method in NinjectWebCommon.cs. However, since I have a MVC3 site in the same solution and want the same Ninject mappings for that site, my CreateKernel looks like this:

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        InfrastructureSetup.RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }
```

3) In InfrastructureSetup.RegisterServices, I have my Ninject mappings:

```
public static class InfrastructureSetup
{
    public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IRepositoryContext>().To<MyEntityFrameworkContext>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IFooRepository>().To<FooRepository>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IBarRepository>().To<BarRepository>().InRequestScope();

        // ... and so on. I want InRequestScope() for the EF context, since
        // otherwise my repositories (which take IRepositoryContext in their 
        // constructors) end up getting different EF contexts, messing things up
    }
}
```

4) I want to also inject stuff (IFooService etc.) to my WCF constructors, so I've edited the Web.config for the WCF project with the advice from Pieter De Rycke:

```
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <!-- Add the Ninject behavior to the WCF service. This is needed to support dependency injection to the WCF constructors -->
                <ninject />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <!-- Add the Ninject behavior extension -->
      <add name="ninject"
        type="MyWCFProject.Infrastructure.NinjectBehaviorExtensionElement, MyWCFProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
```

5) In the MyWCFProject.Infrastructure namespace, I have three files which are basically copy-paste from Pieter:

NinjectBehaviorAttribute.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using Ninject.Web.Common;

namespace MyWCFProject.Infrastructure
{
public class NinjectBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase,
        Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {   
        Type serviceType = serviceDescription.ServiceType;

        // Set up Ninject to support injecting to WCF constructors
        var kernel = new Bootstrapper().Kernel;
        IInstanceProvider instanceProvider = new NinjectInstanceProvider(kernel, serviceType);

        foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher in dispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime = endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime;
                dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = instanceProvider;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
}
```

NinjectBehaviorExtensionElement.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Configuration;

namespace MyWCFProject.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(NinjectBehaviorAttribute); }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new NinjectBehaviorAttribute();
        }
    }
}
```

NinjectInstanceProvider.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using Ninject;

namespace MyWCFProject.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
    {
        private Type serviceType;
        private IKernel kernel;

        public NinjectInstanceProvider(IKernel kernel, Type serviceType)
        {
            this.kernel = kernel;
            this.serviceType = serviceType;
        }

        public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return this.GetInstance(instanceContext, null);
        }

        public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
        {
            return kernel.Get(this.serviceType);
        }

        public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, this solution seems to be working well; dependency injection is working for both the WCF and the MVC3 site, I can request dependencies to be injected to the WCF constructors and the EF context stays around for the duration of the request.