# Setup Ninject for WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject, ninject-extensions

Does anyone have a clear instruction on how to setup Ninject in WCF? been googling around but I cant see any updated guidelines on how to use Ninject in WCF.

Comment: its getting difficult to ask question here in SO. everyone thinks they are smart and everyone expects you to be smart.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using NInject with WCF is the same as using any other DI container. To do this you need to use 3 WCF extensibility points: `InstanceProvider`, `ServiceHost` and `ServiceHostFactory`.

The custom `InstanceProvider` will be used to create service instances by using a constructor with parameters. The code can be seen below.

```
public class NInjectInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider, IContractBehavior
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public NInjectInstanceProvider(IKernel kernel)
    {
        if (kernel == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("kernel");
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        //delegate to GetInstance(InstanceContext)
        return GetInstance(instanceContext);
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        //resolve the service instance
        return kernel.Get(instanceContext.Host.Description.ServiceType);
    }

    public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
    {
        kernel.Release(instance);
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, 
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription,
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription,
        ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
```

This custom instance provider is then applied to every contract in the `ServiceHost` class. This is done by using a contract behavior. This is why the instance provider also implements `IContractBehavior`. You can see that we apply the instance provider in the `ApplyDispatchBehavior` method. The code below presents the `ServiceHost` and `ServiceHostFactory` implementations.

```
public class NInjectServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public NInjectServiceHostFactory()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IDummyDependency>().To<DummyDepencency>();
        //add the rest of the mappings here
    }

    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new NInjectServiceHost(kernel, serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}

public class NInjectServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public NInjectServiceHost(IKernel kernel, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
    {
        if (kernel == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("kernel");
        foreach (var cd in ImplementedContracts.Values)
        {
            cd.Behaviors.Add(new NInjectInstanceProvider(kernel));
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that inside the `ServiceHost` constructor we iterate over all implemented contracts and apply the behavior we need. In our case this is `NInjectInstanceProvider`.

The custom `ServiceHostFactory` is required in order to create the DI container and populate it with mappings. We then override the `CreateServiceHost` method in order to provide our custom `ServiceHost` implementation.

The setup is complete at this point. All you need to do is create a WCF service that has a dependency on `IDummyDependency`. Also, don't forget to set the `Factory` attribute in the svc file like below (right click on svc file, then "View Markup"):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service.DummyService" Factory="Service.NInjectServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Hope this helps. Also, I think NInject offers some implementations for this out of the box in NInject.Extensions.Wcf.dll.

Comment: hi @flo_badea, do you hava a sample project for these codes? can you share it please.

Comment: you can get a sample at https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=3665BE6DBD76EBA7&id=3665BE6DBD76EBA7!355

Comment: another method can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734620/187650

Comment: You have the github code here https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf