# EF dbcontext return an empty dbset in dynamo custom node

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I want to create a drop down list in a Dynamo node to select an item an return properties.

I have a solution in which I have 3 projects. One project is a connector to a database which is used by either of the two other projects.

The two other projects are essentially UI to show the items fetched from the database. One is an WPF application the other one is a Dynamo node.

When I use the WPF application the data from the connector dbcontext return the dbset with the values. But when I use the connector with the Dynamo node, the connector returns an empty dbset. There fore the combobox in the node is empty.

The connector dbcontext

```
using Autodesk.DesignScript.Runtime;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace ConnectToDB
{
    [IsVisibleInDynamoLibrary(false)]
    public partial class ShapesModelContext : DbContext
    {
        [IsVisibleInDynamoLibrary(false)]
        public ShapesModelContext()
            : base("ShapesModelContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<C> C { get; set; }
        public DbSet<C_m> C_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HP> HPs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HP_m> HP_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HSS> HSSes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HSS_m> HSS_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<L> L { get; set; }
        public DbSet<L_m> L_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<M> M { get; set; }
        public DbSet<M_m> M_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MC> MCs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MC_m> MC_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MT> MTs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MT_m> MT_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PIPE> PIPEs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PIPE_m> PIPE_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<S> S { get; set; }
        public DbSet<S_m> S_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ShapesID> ShapesIDs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ST> STs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ST_m> ST_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TwoL> TwoLs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TwoL_m> TwoL_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<W> W { get; set; }
        public DbSet<W_m> W_m { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WT> WTs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WT_m> WT_m { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.C)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.HP)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.HSS)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.L)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.M)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.MC)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.MT)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.PIPE)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.S)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.ST)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.TwoL)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.W)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShapesID>()
                .HasOptional(e => e.WT)
                .WithRequired(e => e.ShapesID);
        }
    }
}
```

The view model and the method to fetch the data.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace ConnectToDB
{
    public class AISC_ShapesViewModel
    {

        private List<string> _Shapes;

        public List<string> Shapes
        {
            get
            {
                return _Shapes;
            }    
               
            set
            {
                _Shapes = value;
            }
        }

        public List<string> LoadSections()
        {
            List<string> thaColl = new List<string>();

            using (var context = new ShapesModelContext())
            {
                var sections = context.ShapesIDs;
                foreach (var section in context.ShapesIDs)
                {
                    thaColl.Add(section.EDI_Std_Nomenclature);
                }

            }

            return Shapes = thaColl;
        }
    }
}
```

The WPF application which show the data correctly in the combobox.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFUI"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ConnectToDB;assembly=ConnectToDB"
        Loaded="Main_Loaded"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:AISC_ShapesViewModel x:Key="thaMidClass"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource thaMidClass}}">
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}"/>
        <Label x:Name="section" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291" Height="22" FontSize="10"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The usercontrol of my Dynamo node which do not show the data.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DynamoUI.Dynamo_UI"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamoUI"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ConnectToDB;assembly=ConnectToDB"
             Loaded="Comboloaded"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="73.5" Width="219.5">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:AISC_ShapesViewModel x:Key="thaMidClass"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource thaMidClass}">
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shapes}"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The node model.

```
using CoreNodeModels;
using Dynamo.Graph.Nodes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DynamoUI
{
    [NodeName("AISC Shapes")]
    [NodeDescription("Query AISC shapes database")]
    [NodeCategory("AISC.Shapes Node")]
    //[InPortNames("A")]
    //[InPortTypes("List")]
    //[InPortDescriptions("List A")]
    [OutPortNames("Output")]
    [OutPortTypes("Dictionary")]
    [OutPortDescriptions("Shape properties dictionary")]
    [IsDesignScriptCompatible]
    class AISC_Shape_Node_Model: NodeModel
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public AISC_Shape_Node_Model()
        {
            RegisterAllPorts();
        }

    }
}
```

The node view.

```
using Dynamo.Controls;
using Dynamo.Wpf;

namespace DynamoUI
{
    class AISC_Shape_Node_View : INodeViewCustomization<AISC_Shape_Node_Model>
    {
        public void CustomizeView(AISC_Shape_Node_Model model, NodeView nodeView)
        {
            var ui = new Dynamo_UI();
            nodeView.inputGrid.Children.Add(ui);
            ui.DataContext = model;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The connection string.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ShapesModelContext" connectionString="data source=MyDatabase;initial catalog=AISC_Shapes_V15;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

With Dynamo node.

[image]

With WPF application.
[image]

At each time I use the WPF front end, this method is called.

```
        public List<string> LoadSections()
        {
            List<string> thaColl = new List<string>();

            using (var context = new ShapesModelContext())
            {
                var sections = context.ShapesIDs;
                foreach (var section in context.ShapesIDs)
                {
                    thaColl.Add(section.EDI_Std_Nomenclature);
                }

            }

            return Shapes = thaColl;
        }
```

And, in debug steps we can see that the " ShapesModelContext " which inherits from EF DbContext  is created and ShapesIDs DbSet is assigned to sections. The code enters in the for loop and iterates through the DbSet.

But when I use the Dynamo NodeModel as front end the same code gets executed but at the for loop, it checks the DbSet and exits the loop immediately because the DbSet is empty.

Comment: What is the connection string for each of the 3 projects?  Usually if the connection string is  different the results will be different.

Comment: The connection string is the same for all projects. And I switch for one ui project to the other. When I use the WPF app it works fine but when I use the Dynamo node the combobox is empty.

Comment: Why is the DataContext different?

Comment: I use the same dbcontext for both the WPF application and the Dynamo node. Why do you think there are different?

Comment: 1) <Grid DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource thaMidClass}}">
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}"/>
        <Label x:Name="section" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="173,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="291" Height="22" FontSize="10"/>

Comment: 2) <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource thaMidClass}">
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="193" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shapes}"/>

Comment: I changed the data context 2 to be the same as 1 and the problem remains.

Comment: The context is empty.  Probably the query to fill context when application starts is not working.  I will do some research.

Comment: Did you see this website : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.html

Comment: Thank you very much jdweng. Dynamo here stands for DynamoBim from Autodesk. It's a visual programming interface.

Comment: Still it is a visual interface for a database connection.  I'm not sure but it probably is using the Dynamo interface in my last link to connect to the database.  It appears the root issue is the context is empty.   When code runs it must first fill the context before a query is run (or simultaneously get data from database as query is running).   It looks like a constructor needs to run from the web.config to start this process.  Read answers at this posting for better explanation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466886/using-ninject-wcf-extension-with-wcf-web-service

Comment: Thank you very much! I will investigate on that side.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Dynamo uses its own connection string. The connection string points to:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb
```

And the initial catalog name is defined by the connection string name found in the DbContext.

```
Initial Catalog=ShapesModelContext
```

Therefore I changed my LoadSections() method to specify the correct connection string.

The original code was:

```
        public List<string> LoadSections()
        {
            List<string> thaColl = new List<string>();

            using (var context = new ShapesModelContext())
            {
                var sections = context.ShapesIDs;
                foreach (var section in context.ShapesIDs)
                {
                    thaColl.Add(section.EDI_Std_Nomenclature);
                }

            }

            return Shapes = thaColl;
        }
```

Now with the added connection string.

```
            using (var context = new ShapesModelContext())
            {
                context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "data source=XXXXX;initial catalog=XXXXXXXX;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
                var sections = context.ShapesIDs;
                foreach (var section in sections)
                {
                    thaColl.Add(section.EDI_Std_Nomenclature);
                }
            }

            return Shapes = thaColl;
```